# For loop getFileById() throwing error: "No item with the given ID could be found....."

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all I am very new to programming and I am just figuring things out as I go. I am trying to write an app script that will copy specific files by ID (IDs are stored in a google sheet file) into this new folder that is created when a form is submitted. But my for loop throws and error saying: "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 30, file "App Script""

Even though when I run the code with each file (byID) individually it works. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. (The IDs in the code below are not the actual IDs)

```
function SheetAutomation(){
    function getSheetById(id) {
      return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(
      function(s) {return s.getSheetId() === id;}
      )[0];
    }

  var sheet_form_res = getSheetById(1692343941);
  var lr = sheet_form_res.getLastRow();
  var casenumber = sheet_form_res.getRange(lr,1).getValue();
  Logger.log(casenumber);

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1tr2A3e3edwelB8dgkN8tgdPYv8T8V6");
  var newFolder = folder.createFolder(casenumber);
  var newFolderID = newFolder.getId();
  Logger.log('newFolderID: ' + newFolderID);
  var casefolderid = sheet_form_res.getRange(lr, 7).setValue(newFolderID);
  Logger.log('Casefolder id: ' + casefolderid.getValues());

  var sheet_dsd_image_id = getSheetById(1233563458640);
  var num_dsd_images = sheet_dsd_image_id.getRange(lr,1).getValue();
  Logger.log('num_dsd_images: ' + num_dsd_images);

  for (var i=0; i<=num_dsd_images; i++){
    var image_id = sheet_dsd_image_id.getRange(lr,i+1).getValue();
    Logger.log(image_id);
    // The line of code that doesn't work
    var image_file = DriveApp.getFileById(image_id);
    Logger.log(image_file);
  }
};
```

I replaced the for loop with the following to see if I really did not have access to the files, but this seems to work, I just can't make it work through the loop

```
  var image_id_1 = sheet_dsd_image_id.getRange(lr,2).getValue();
  var image_file_1 = DriveApp.getFileById(image_id_1);
  Logger.log(image_file_1);
  image_file_1.makeCopy(newFolder);

  var image_id_2 = sheet_dsd_image_id.getRange(lr,3).getValue();
  var image_file_2 = DriveApp.getFileById(image_id_2);
  Logger.log(image_file_2);
  image_file_2.makeCopy(newFolder);

  var image_id_3 = sheet_dsd_image_id.getRange(lr,4).getValue();
  var image_file_3 = DriveApp.getFileById(image_id_3);
  Logger.log(image_file_3);
  image_file_3.makeCopy(newFolder);
```

The project triggers are as follows:
[Project Trigger window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pue6z.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, it seems likely that this is an off by one error.  Are you sure that your for loop is within the range you expect?  You define your range with `<=`:

`for (var i=0; i<=num_dsd_images; i++)`

This means if `num_dsd_images` is 3, the following values of `i` are used: 1, 2, 3, 4.  Is that correct?  Based on your variable name, I would expect only 3 images not 4.

If you use `<` and not `<=`, the values for `i` would be: 1, 2, 3.  With this change, your loop would like:

```
for (var i=0; i < num_dsd_images; i++){
    var image_id = sheet_dsd_image_id.getRange(lr,i+1).getValue();
    Logger.log(image_id);
    // The line of code that doesn't work
    var image_file = DriveApp.getFileById(image_id);
    Logger.log(image_file);
 }
```

Alternatively, you could 1-index your range and use `<=` like this:
`for (var i = 1; i <= num_dsd_images; i++)`

Comment: This worked: following changes made it work
 for (var i=1; i<num_dsd_images; i++){
    Logger.log('i: '+ i);
    var image_id = sheet_dsd_image_id.getRange(lr,i+1).getValue();